# Fitting a JTable Inside a Panel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using a JTable and adding it to a panel which uses a gridbaglayout like so:

```
JTable qdbs = new JTable(rowData, columnNamesVector);
qdbs.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

panel.add(qdbs, c);
```

I don't want the table to be in a scroll pane, but I do want the table to take up the entire width of the panel. How would I accomplish this?

An SSCCE as requested:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestFrame();
    }

    public static class TestFrame extends JFrame{
    public TestFrame() {
        this.setTitle("SSCCE");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        JTable testTable = new JTable(10,2);
        panel.add(testTable, c);

        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    }

}
```

I would like this table to always take up the entire width of the panel (except the insets). Currently the table does not change size when the frame is resized.

Comment: Why did you post a SSCCE? You where given a working example a week earlier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add constrains to tell the layout what to do with more space. In your SSCCE add these items:

```
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
  c.weightx = 1;
  c.weighty = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
        JTable table = new JTable(5, 5);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.add(table, gbc);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If you need more help post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: weightx and fill solve the problem as stated. And I agree with mKorbel that you never really want to place a JTable without an associated JScrollPane (JTables rely heavily on scrolls to make certain rows visible and other operations)

Answer (score 4):

`c` is a `GridBagConstraint` or something along those lines, I imagine? The very simplest thing to do would be to set the `LayoutManager` of the `JPanel` to a `BorderLayout`, then just add with the constraint `BorderLayout.CENTER` .

Comment: Yes, but I need the JPanel layout manager to be a grid bag layout, not a border layout.

Comment: @Alex: You can nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager in effect nesting layouts. If Ernest's suggestion doesn't help, perhaps your best bet is to create a small compilable and runnable program that we all can run and that demonstrates your problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Alex Bliskovsky: GridBagLayout is old and often unnecessary, just go with BorderLayout.

Answer (score 4):

hmmm

Alex Bliskovsky wrote `panel.add(qdbs, c);`

that's wrong, not, never do that, you are forgot wrap you [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to the [ScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and then you can play with some of [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), for related examples for LayoutManagers check [GridBagConstraints](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1480__GridBagConstraints.htm) for [GrigBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: I specifically said that I did not want my JTable to be inside a scroll pane, and I am already using the GridBagLayout.

Comment: @Alex Bliskovsky :-) be sure that I saw your requirerments, but that's my peaceFullFace reactions, maybe is another as you ..., but is here :-) much luck

Answer (score 4):

The following frame will correctly resize the table when the frame is resized.

```
public class Sandbox {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestFrame();
}

public static class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    public TestFrame() {
        this.setTitle("SSCCE");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        JTable testTable = new JTable(10, 2);
        panel.add(testTable, c);

        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps with:

```
GridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagContraints.BOTH;
```

Comment: Will this specifically fill the width? It's default height is fine and should not change.