# How to make a JTable without a JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have done some pretty decent searching and i cant quite fine what im looking for. basically i want a JTable in a JPanel and for that JPanel to re-size itself per the size of the JTable. i know the usual way of implementing a JTable is to use the JScrollpane but in this circumstance it is unnecessary and it makes my program look ... messy.

the reason i cant find the answer i need is everytime someone asks about a JTable in a JPanel someone gives them the answer of putting it in the scrollpane. im aware of the advantages to using the scrollpane but in this circumstance they aren't advantageous.

Comment: You might want to add a screenshot to explain why you think it looks messy?

Comment: i guess i should explain. im using the JGraphX library and trying to create a custom vertex layout. its done by using normal swing components. each vertex has a table that contains information that doesnt contain a huge number of rows and 5 columns. having a scrollpane on each node is messy and having just the jtable with info easily viewable would make it more intuitive as well as cleaner

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. yes is possible add [JTable to the JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050708/fitting-a-jtable-inside-a-panel), notice with a few row that fills real screen resolution
2. you have to add `TableHeader` separatelly to the container too, otherwise isn't added, nor to be visible, for `JTable` into `JScrollPane` isn't required add or define `TableHeader` separatelly
3. better could be to remove borders from `JScrollPane.setBorders(null)` and with to disable `VERTICAL` and `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR` to `NEVER`
4. for shrinking the wider `JScrollPane` to fits to the `JTables Dimension` is possible to use `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());`

Comment: thank you very much. i searched these forums and the JGraphx forums forever and didnt see that post. the headers arent really an issue for this. so ill probably just do what they did in the link!

Comment: @mKorbel Do you have any examples in which you add a `JTableHeader` to a container or a `JComponent`?

Comment: @Igor use JButtons instead of JTableHeader in the case that you want to separate JTableHeader without JTable

Comment: @mKorbel I'm not sure what you mean, but I want to be able to put a JTableHeader at the top of any component (JPanel, JComponent etc...)

Comment: :-) then to use JButtons (layed by GridLayout) instead of JTableHeader, better of ways without side effects

Comment: @mKorbel Good idea, thanks. They would look almost, if not completely, the same on _Windows_, but wouldn't it look weird on a _Mac_?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your JPanel and return the value of your JTable's `getPreferredSize()`:

```
final JTable table = new JTable();

JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return table.getPreferredSize();
    }
}
```